# Display part of the data from view's model at a time (ASP.NET MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I am completely new to ASP.NET MVC, so the question might sound silly.

I have a view that should display a part of the data from it's model at a time. And there are buttons that should trigger which part of the data gets shown.

So far, I have encapsulated each part of the data into a div and added buttons. I have also added a function that returns CSS style for a given id (basically, it returns `display:visible` or `display:none`).

I assume that I'll be able to wire up event handlers for buttons. But I am completely stuck at redrawing/updating of div elements. I mean I don't understand how should I cause divs to update their style.

Could you please help me to show/hide div elements and buttons dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be standard javascript (or in your case jquery).  It is unrelated to MVC3.  Once you have the view built that includes all your divs with content, you call $('#div_id').show() or $('#div_id').hide() to show or hide.  You can also use many other methods that have related animations, but that should get you started.

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Basic_Show_and_Hide

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('buttonClass/IDhere').click(function (){
$('theDivYouWantToShowClass/IDhere').toggle();
});
```

Comment: I tried your code but I am getting javascript error about '$' being undefined. What might cause the error?

Comment: Never mind, I got the answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530311/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-is-undefined)