# Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to hide/show elements in a view using following code:

```
$('buttonClass/IDhere').click(function (){
$('theDivYouWantToShowClass/IDhere').toggle();
});
```

However, I am keep getting

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined
```

What might be the issue and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ is defined by default when you load jquery.  I would try and use jquery() to see if somehow $ is being unloaded etc.  You can also load up firebug and hit the page.  It should show up as  a global variable/function.  NOTE:  You can also setup jquery to not setup the short hand "$".

Comment: How can I check if jquery is loaded? I tried to add `jquery()` in javascript block before first use of '$' but it didn't help. I just got `'jquery()' is undefined`.

Comment: Think you could say how you figure it out??

Comment: @meanbunny See this [link](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html).

Answer (score 8):

This thread is pretty old, but I think an answer in the thread would be nice. I agree with the previous two answers - it's likely because jQuery wasn't loaded. You can load it this way (usually toward the top of the file):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(or whatever the current version of jQuery is).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like jQuery hasn't been loaded yet.

Answer (score 3):

did you make sure download the jquery javascript file and link in to your html/aspx page before attempting to use jquery scripting?

you need to:

1. download the jquery code/file from:
   http://jquery.com/
2. copy the file (jquery-1.8.3.min.js) you just downloaded somewhere into your web project directory/folder
3. then insert the link to this file into html/aspx page:

1. now try to run webpage

references:
www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bf9Gs-09uzQ

www.ajaxtutorials.com/javascript/introduction-to-jquery-learn-jquery-from-scratch-in-asp-net-4-0/

Answer (score 0):

since it looks like your trying to target classes and ID's - try this

```
$('.buttonClass #IDhere').click(function (){
$('.theDivYouWantToShowClass #IDhere').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a definite case of jQuery module not being loaded. In my case, common.js had a jQuery related script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var divSessionWarning = $("#idivWarn");
divSesWarning.load(divSesWarning.data("src"));
});
```

This was called in header.jsp. Swapping the sequence of loading the jQuery followed by the common.js resolved the issue.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/JAVASCRIPT/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JAVASCRIPT/mod/common.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is called then make sure jQuery is loaded before the stylesheet as its likely that calls it

Comment: could you please expand on how your answer addresses the specific problem as described by OP.