# JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined when trying to run sample code

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

I am trying to run the sample chart code from
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series
but its breaking. I am getting following error

> Unhandled exception at line 12, column 7  0x800a1391 - JavaScript
>   runtime error: '$' is undefined

The code:

```
  $(function () {
      $('#container').highcharts({
          chart: {
              zoomType: 'x',
              spacingRight: 20
          },
          title: {
              text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate from 2006 through 2008'
          },
          subtitle: {
              text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                  'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' :
                  'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
          },
          xAxis: {
              type: 'datetime',
              maxZoom: 14 * 24 * 3600000, // fourteen days
              title: {
                  text: null
              }
          },
          yAxis: {
              title: {
                  text: 'Exchange rate'
              }
          },
          tooltip: {
              shared: true
          },
          legend: {
              enabled: false
          },
          plotOptions: {
              area: {
                  fillColor: {
                      linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                      stops: [
                          [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                          [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                      ]
                  },
                  lineWidth: 1,
                  marker: {
                      enabled: false
                  },
                  shadow: false,
                  states: {
                      hover: {
                          lineWidth: 1
                      }
                  },
                  threshold: null
              }
          },

          series: [{
              type: 'area',
              name: 'USD to EUR',
              pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
              pointStart: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 01),
              data: [
                  0.8446, 0.8445, 0.8444, 0.8451, 0.8418, 0.8264, 0.8258, 0.8232, 0.8233, 0.8258,
                  0.8283, 0.8278, 0.8256, 0.8292, 0.8239, 0.8239, 0.8245, 0.8265, 0.8261, 0.8269,
                  0.8273, 0.8244, 0.8244, 0.8172, 0.8139, 0.8146, 0.8164, 0.82, 0.8269, 0.8269,
                  0.8269, 0.8258, 0.8247, 0.8286, 0.8289, 0.8316, 0.832, 0.8333, 0.8352, 0.8357,
                  0.8355, 0.8354, 0.8403, 0.8403, 0.8406, 0.8403, 0.8396, 0.8418, 0.8409, 0.8384,
                  0.8386, 0.8372, 0.839, 0.84, 0.8389, 0.84, 0.8423, 0.8423, 0.8435, 0.8422,
                  0.838, 0.8373, 0.8316, 0.8303, 0.8303, 0.8302, 0.8369, 0.84, 0.8385, 0.84,
                  0.8401, 0.8402, 0.8381, 0.8351, 0.8314, 0.8273, 0.8213, 0.8207, 0.8207, 0.8215,
                  0.8242, 0.8273, 0.8301, 0.8346, 0.8312, 0.8312, 0.8312, 0.8306, 0.8327, 0.8282,
                  0.824, 0.8255, 0.8256, 0.8273, 0.8209, 0.8151, 0.8149, 0.8213, 0.8273, 0.8273,
                  0.8261, 0.8252, 0.824, 0.8262, 0.8258, 0.8261, 0.826, 0.8199, 0.8153, 0.8097,
                  0.8101, 0.8119, 0.8107, 0.8105, 0.8084, 0.8069, 0.8047, 0.8023, 0.7965, 0.7919,
                  0.7921, 0.7922, 0.7934, 0.7918, 0.7915, 0.787, 0.7861, 0.7861, 0.7853, 0.7867,
                  0.7827, 0.7834, 0.7766, 0.7751, 0.7739, 0.7767, 0.7802, 0.7788, 0.7828, 0.7816,
                  0.7829, 0.783, 0.7829, 0.7781, 0.7811, 0.7831, 0.7826, 0.7855, 0.7855, 0.7845,
                  0.7798, 0.7777, 0.7822, 0.7785, 0.7744, 0.7743, 0.7726, 0.7766, 0.7806, 0.785,
                  0.7907, 0.7912, 0.7913, 0.7931, 0.7952, 0.7951, 0.7928, 0.791, 0.7913, 0.7912,
                  0.7941, 0.7953, 0.7921, 0.7919, 0.7968, 0.7999, 0.7999, 0.7974, 0.7942, 0.796,
                  0.7969, 0.7862, 0.7821, 0.7821, 0.7821, 0.7811, 0.7833, 0.7849, 0.7819, 0.7809,
                  0.7809, 0.7827, 0.7848, 0.785, 0.7873, 0.7894, 0.7907, 0.7909, 0.7947, 0.7987,
                  0.799, 0.7927, 0.79, 0.7878, 0.7878, 0.7907, 0.7922, 0.7937, 0.786, 0.787,
                  0.7838, 0.7838, 0.7837, 0.7836, 0.7806, 0.7825, 0.7798, 0.777, 0.777, 0.7772,
                  0.7793, 0.7788, 0.7785, 0.7832, 0.7865, 0.7865, 0.7853, 0.7847, 0.7809, 0.778,
                  0.7799, 0.78, 0.7801, 0.7765, 0.7785, 0.7811, 0.782, 0.7835, 0.7845, 0.7844,
                  0.782, 0.7811, 0.7795, 0.7794, 0.7806, 0.7794, 0.7794, 0.7778, 0.7793, 0.7808,
                  0.7824, 0.787, 0.7894, 0.7893, 0.7882, 0.7871, 0.7882, 0.7871, 0.7878, 0.79,
                  0.7901, 0.7898, 0.7879, 0.7886, 0.7858, 0.7814, 0.7825, 0.7826, 0.7826, 0.786,
                  0.7878, 0.7868, 0.7883, 0.7893, 0.7892, 0.7876, 0.785, 0.787, 0.7873, 0.7901,
                  0.7936, 0.7939, 0.7938, 0.7956, 0.7975, 0.7978, 0.7972, 0.7995, 0.7995, 0.7994,
                  0.7976, 0.7977, 0.796, 0.7922, 0.7928, 0.7929, 0.7948, 0.797, 0.7953, 0.7907,
                  0.7872, 0.7852, 0.7852, 0.786, 0.7862, 0.7836, 0.7837, 0.784, 0.7867, 0.7867,
                  0.7869, 0.7837, 0.7827, 0.7825, 0.7779, 0.7791, 0.779, 0.7787, 0.78, 0.7807,
                  0.7803, 0.7817, 0.7799, 0.7799, 0.7795, 0.7801, 0.7765, 0.7725, 0.7683, 0.7641,
                  0.7639, 0.7616, 0.7608, 0.759, 0.7582, 0.7539, 0.75, 0.75, 0.7507, 0.7505,
                  0.7516, 0.7522, 0.7531, 0.7577, 0.7577, 0.7582, 0.755, 0.7542, 0.7576, 0.7616,
                  0.7648, 0.7648, 0.7641, 0.7614, 0.757, 0.7587, 0.7588, 0.762, 0.762, 0.7617,
                  0.7618, 0.7615, 0.7612, 0.7596, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.7547, 0.7549, 0.7613,
                  0.7655, 0.7693, 0.7694, 0.7688, 0.7678, 0.7708, 0.7727, 0.7749, 0.7741, 0.7741,
                  0.7732, 0.7727, 0.7737, 0.7724, 0.7712, 0.772, 0.7721, 0.7717, 0.7704, 0.769,
                  0.7711, 0.774, 0.7745, 0.7745, 0.774, 0.7716, 0.7713, 0.7678, 0.7688, 0.7718,
                  0.7718, 0.7728, 0.7729, 0.7698, 0.7685, 0.7681, 0.769, 0.769, 0.7698, 0.7699,
                  0.7651, 0.7613, 0.7616, 0.7614, 0.7614, 0.7607, 0.7602, 0.7611, 0.7622, 0.7615,
                  0.7598, 0.7598, 0.7592, 0.7573, 0.7566, 0.7567, 0.7591, 0.7582, 0.7585, 0.7613,
                  0.7631, 0.7615, 0.76, 0.7613, 0.7627, 0.7627, 0.7608, 0.7583, 0.7575, 0.7562,
                  0.752, 0.7512, 0.7512, 0.7517, 0.752, 0.7511, 0.748, 0.7509, 0.7531, 0.7531,
                  0.7527, 0.7498, 0.7493, 0.7504, 0.75, 0.7491, 0.7491, 0.7485, 0.7484, 0.7492,
                  0.7471, 0.7459, 0.7477, 0.7477, 0.7483, 0.7458, 0.7448, 0.743, 0.7399, 0.7395,
                  0.7395, 0.7378, 0.7382, 0.7362, 0.7355, 0.7348, 0.7361, 0.7361, 0.7365, 0.7362,
                  0.7331, 0.7339, 0.7344, 0.7327, 0.7327, 0.7336, 0.7333, 0.7359, 0.7359, 0.7372,
                  0.736, 0.736, 0.735, 0.7365, 0.7384, 0.7395, 0.7413, 0.7397, 0.7396, 0.7385,
                  0.7378, 0.7366, 0.74, 0.7411, 0.7406, 0.7405, 0.7414, 0.7431, 0.7431, 0.7438,
                  0.7443, 0.7443, 0.7443, 0.7434, 0.7429, 0.7442, 0.744, 0.7439, 0.7437, 0.7437,
                  0.7429, 0.7403, 0.7399, 0.7418, 0.7468, 0.748, 0.748, 0.749, 0.7494, 0.7522,
                  0.7515, 0.7502, 0.7472, 0.7472, 0.7462, 0.7455, 0.7449, 0.7467, 0.7458, 0.7427,
                  0.7427, 0.743, 0.7429, 0.744, 0.743, 0.7422, 0.7388, 0.7388, 0.7369, 0.7345,
                  0.7345, 0.7345, 0.7352, 0.7341, 0.7341, 0.734, 0.7324, 0.7272, 0.7264, 0.7255,
                  0.7258, 0.7258, 0.7256, 0.7257, 0.7247, 0.7243, 0.7244, 0.7235, 0.7235, 0.7235,
                  0.7235, 0.7262, 0.7288, 0.7301, 0.7337, 0.7337, 0.7324, 0.7297, 0.7317, 0.7315,
                  0.7288, 0.7263, 0.7263, 0.7242, 0.7253, 0.7264, 0.727, 0.7312, 0.7305, 0.7305,
                  0.7318, 0.7358, 0.7409, 0.7454, 0.7437, 0.7424, 0.7424, 0.7415, 0.7419, 0.7414,
                  0.7377, 0.7355, 0.7315, 0.7315, 0.732, 0.7332, 0.7346, 0.7328, 0.7323, 0.734,
                  0.734, 0.7336, 0.7351, 0.7346, 0.7321, 0.7294, 0.7266, 0.7266, 0.7254, 0.7242,
                  0.7213, 0.7197, 0.7209, 0.721, 0.721, 0.721, 0.7209, 0.7159, 0.7133, 0.7105,
                  0.7099, 0.7099, 0.7093, 0.7093, 0.7076, 0.707, 0.7049, 0.7012, 0.7011, 0.7019,
                  0.7046, 0.7063, 0.7089, 0.7077, 0.7077, 0.7077, 0.7091, 0.7118, 0.7079, 0.7053,
                  0.705, 0.7055, 0.7055, 0.7045, 0.7051, 0.7051, 0.7017, 0.7, 0.6995, 0.6994,
                  0.7014, 0.7036, 0.7021, 0.7002, 0.6967, 0.695, 0.695, 0.6939, 0.694, 0.6922,
                  0.6919, 0.6914, 0.6894, 0.6891, 0.6904, 0.689, 0.6834, 0.6823, 0.6807, 0.6815,
                  0.6815, 0.6847, 0.6859, 0.6822, 0.6827, 0.6837, 0.6823, 0.6822, 0.6822, 0.6792,
                  0.6746, 0.6735, 0.6731, 0.6742, 0.6744, 0.6739, 0.6731, 0.6761, 0.6761, 0.6785,
                  0.6818, 0.6836, 0.6823, 0.6805, 0.6793, 0.6849, 0.6833, 0.6825, 0.6825, 0.6816,
                  0.6799, 0.6813, 0.6809, 0.6868, 0.6933, 0.6933, 0.6945, 0.6944, 0.6946, 0.6964,
                  0.6965, 0.6956, 0.6956, 0.695, 0.6948, 0.6928, 0.6887, 0.6824, 0.6794, 0.6794,
                  0.6803, 0.6855, 0.6824, 0.6791, 0.6783, 0.6785, 0.6785, 0.6797, 0.68, 0.6803,
                  0.6805, 0.676, 0.677, 0.677, 0.6736, 0.6726, 0.6764, 0.6821, 0.6831, 0.6842,
                  0.6842, 0.6887, 0.6903, 0.6848, 0.6824, 0.6788, 0.6814, 0.6814, 0.6797, 0.6769,
                  0.6765, 0.6733, 0.6729, 0.6758, 0.6758, 0.675, 0.678, 0.6833, 0.6856, 0.6903,
                  0.6896, 0.6896, 0.6882, 0.6879, 0.6862, 0.6852, 0.6823, 0.6813, 0.6813, 0.6822,
                  0.6802, 0.6802, 0.6784, 0.6748, 0.6747, 0.6747, 0.6748, 0.6733, 0.665, 0.6611,
                  0.6583, 0.659, 0.659, 0.6581, 0.6578, 0.6574, 0.6532, 0.6502, 0.6514, 0.6514,
                  0.6507, 0.651, 0.6489, 0.6424, 0.6406, 0.6382, 0.6382, 0.6341, 0.6344, 0.6378,
                  0.6439, 0.6478, 0.6481, 0.6481, 0.6494, 0.6438, 0.6377, 0.6329, 0.6336, 0.6333,
                  0.6333, 0.633, 0.6371, 0.6403, 0.6396, 0.6364, 0.6356, 0.6356, 0.6368, 0.6357,
                  0.6354, 0.632, 0.6332, 0.6328, 0.6331, 0.6342, 0.6321, 0.6302, 0.6278, 0.6308,
                  0.6324, 0.6324, 0.6307, 0.6277, 0.6269, 0.6335, 0.6392, 0.64, 0.6401, 0.6396,
                  0.6407, 0.6423, 0.6429, 0.6472, 0.6485, 0.6486, 0.6467, 0.6444, 0.6467, 0.6509,
                  0.6478, 0.6461, 0.6461, 0.6468, 0.6449, 0.647, 0.6461, 0.6452, 0.6422, 0.6422,
                  0.6425, 0.6414, 0.6366, 0.6346, 0.635, 0.6346, 0.6346, 0.6343, 0.6346, 0.6379,
                  0.6416, 0.6442, 0.6431, 0.6431, 0.6435, 0.644, 0.6473, 0.6469, 0.6386, 0.6356,
                  0.634, 0.6346, 0.643, 0.6452, 0.6467, 0.6506, 0.6504, 0.6503, 0.6481, 0.6451,
                  0.645, 0.6441, 0.6414, 0.6409, 0.6409, 0.6428, 0.6431, 0.6418, 0.6371, 0.6349,
                  0.6333, 0.6334, 0.6338, 0.6342, 0.632, 0.6318, 0.637, 0.6368, 0.6368, 0.6383,
                  0.6371, 0.6371, 0.6355, 0.632, 0.6277, 0.6276, 0.6291, 0.6274, 0.6293, 0.6311,
                  0.631, 0.6312, 0.6312, 0.6304, 0.6294, 0.6348, 0.6378, 0.6368, 0.6368, 0.6368,
                  0.636, 0.637, 0.6418, 0.6411, 0.6435, 0.6427, 0.6427, 0.6419, 0.6446, 0.6468,
                  0.6487, 0.6594, 0.6666, 0.6666, 0.6678, 0.6712, 0.6705, 0.6718, 0.6784, 0.6811,
                  0.6811, 0.6794, 0.6804, 0.6781, 0.6756, 0.6735, 0.6763, 0.6762, 0.6777, 0.6815,
                  0.6802, 0.678, 0.6796, 0.6817, 0.6817, 0.6832, 0.6877, 0.6912, 0.6914, 0.7009,
                  0.7012, 0.701, 0.7005, 0.7076, 0.7087, 0.717, 0.7105, 0.7031, 0.7029, 0.7006,
                  0.7035, 0.7045, 0.6956, 0.6988, 0.6915, 0.6914, 0.6859, 0.6778, 0.6815, 0.6815,
                  0.6843, 0.6846, 0.6846, 0.6923, 0.6997, 0.7098, 0.7188, 0.7232, 0.7262, 0.7266,
                  0.7359, 0.7368, 0.7337, 0.7317, 0.7387, 0.7467, 0.7461, 0.7366, 0.7319, 0.7361,
                  0.7437, 0.7432, 0.7461, 0.7461, 0.7454, 0.7549, 0.7742, 0.7801, 0.7903, 0.7876,
                  0.7928, 0.7991, 0.8007, 0.7823, 0.7661, 0.785, 0.7863, 0.7862, 0.7821, 0.7858,
                  0.7731, 0.7779, 0.7844, 0.7866, 0.7864, 0.7788, 0.7875, 0.7971, 0.8004, 0.7857,
                  0.7932, 0.7938, 0.7927, 0.7918, 0.7919, 0.7989, 0.7988, 0.7949, 0.7948, 0.7882,
                  0.7745, 0.771, 0.775, 0.7791, 0.7882, 0.7882, 0.7899, 0.7905, 0.7889, 0.7879,
                  0.7855, 0.7866, 0.7865, 0.7795, 0.7758, 0.7717, 0.761, 0.7497, 0.7471, 0.7473,
                  0.7407, 0.7288, 0.7074, 0.6927, 0.7083, 0.7191, 0.719, 0.7153, 0.7156, 0.7158,
                  0.714, 0.7119, 0.7129, 0.7129, 0.7049, 0.7095
              ]
          }]
      });
  });
```

Comment: You probably need to include the jQuery library at first. (The provided jsFiddle from the site also includes jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/)

Comment: @b_dubb It's a scripting language like JavaScript :-) [You can even add numbers](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: wow. internets sure are hard. especially when your javascripts have numbers in them

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530311/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-is-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

include this in your head section. `$` is an alias for `Jquery.`